# Angular2 material autocomplete issues

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material

I have 2 material autocomplite inputs in form.

1) First one works with dynamic data, and works good except arrow buttons of keyboard don't work. It is impossible to chose an option with arrows and enter.

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="autoData" formControlName="autoData" matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto" (keyup)="getData($event.target.value)">
            <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
                    <mat-option  (onSelectionChange)="getMoreData(option.text)" *ngFor="let option of testData; let in=index" [value]="option">
                        {{ option.text }}
                    </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

2) Second one works with static array of data. The problem - it shows all possible options, and do not filtered options when typing letters in input. Also a problem with keyboard.

The code is the same

> {{option.name + " " + option.cat}}

Answer (score 1):

> I have done using angular with dynamic data and also filtered that data

html file

```
     <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput [(ngModel)] = "builderCompanyName" placeholder="Builder Company Name" [formControl]="CommercialControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
          <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let name of builderCompanyNameArray | listFilter:builderCompanyName" [value]="name" (click)="select(CommercialControl.value)">
              {{ name }}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-autocomplete>
        </mat-form-field>
```

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VM16y.png]
>
> You can search string also in mat-autocomplete

pipe file

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

 @Pipe({
   name: "listFilter" 
 })

 export class ListFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
 transform(items: any[], searchText: string): any[] {
  if (!items) return [];
  if (!searchText) return items;
  searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
  return items.filter(it => {
    // console.log(it);
    return it.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
   });
  }
 }
```

> Below is the filtered result

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8WJ5.png]

> Hope this will help you.Thank you

Comment: Thanks, but what about if i have arrary of objects? options = [
        {"id":1,"name":"colour","cat":"red"},
        {"id":2,"name":"colour","cat":"blue},
        {"id":3,"name":"colour","cat":"green"}
      ]; - How to filter in that case?

Comment: For array of object look into my this answer.It might help you , link is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47631908/filter-on-multiple-columns-in-a-table-using-one-pipe-in-angular/47668167#47668167  

Thank You